# Pass url href in Django

Tags: python, html, django

The problem is, how can I pass data from html to my views, based on selected row button in my html. As you can see the trigger to pass data is through Submit button which I've been using href and get the id. The problem is there's no arguments not found in my url.It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

[image]

*scanned.html*

```
{% for folder in folder_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'view_gallery' folder.id %}"  class="btn btn-outline-teal" >Submit</a>
{% endfor %}
```

*Url.py*

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('scanned_docs/',views.scanned_docs, name='scanned_docs'),
    path('view_gallery/<str:pk>/',views.view_gallery, name='view_gallery')
]
```

*views.py*

```
def view_gallery(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        image = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = pk)
        data = {'photos':image} 
        return render(request, 'view_gallery.html', data) 

@login_required(login_url='log_permission')  
def scanned_docs(request, reason=""):   #I think there's no problem here in this function
    folder =  folder_info.objects.all()
    data = {'folder_list':folder}
    return render(request, 'scanned.html',data)
```

Comment: Firstly in your view_gallery view you are expecting a POST method but you are putting a link there which would be a get method. Your problem is likely because in scanned.html there is a line like `{% url 'view_gallery' %}`

Comment: Did you try : path('view_gallery/<int:pk>/',views.view_gallery, name='view_gallery')

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Thanks for your response, Did you mean in my href?`{% url 'view_gallery' %} `. I'm putting that to pass it to my url through getting the specific ID.  Yes I'm aware the it needs a POST in my function and  need some help and idea how to fix this problem :)

Comment: @Bea Thanks for your response , Yes I've already tried using your suggestion buy the result is the same, I don't know why.

Comment: @BootCamp the `{% url 'view_gallery' folder.id %}` is correct, somewhere in your template you also have `{% url 'view_gallery' %}` without the folder id.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat  Sorry Just make a typo in my last comment and I can't edit it now  `{% url 'view_gallery' folder.id %} `  is the actually I'm been using and still don't know where can I find the  exact  problem.

Comment: @BootCamp : Try to have a look on your template "scanned.html" to see if you do not have a {% url 'view_gallery' %} without folder.id as suggested by Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: @Bea Yes I see what the problem now I forgot to erase the uncomment view_gallery, but it suppose not should functioning, but the problem now is how can I add  `POST` request when passing data to url? like @ABDUL Aziz first comment?

Comment: @ Abdul Aziz Barkat `The view app.views.view_gallery didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`  It is possible to pass data using href and then call a POST request inorder to meet the conditions?

Comment: remove the condition `if request.method == 'POST':` from your view "view_gallery"

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Yes that's solve the problem but just a confusion Is there any way to pass data using href and then call a POST request inorder to meet the conditions? For security purposes, What If I directly access the URL without making a request?

Comment: You use the POST method when you want to send some data to the server, refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) to understand http methods. If you want some sort of security to a view, you likely want the user to be logged in to your site use the [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) for that.